# AngularJS call common controller function from outside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

My basic premise is I want to call back to the server to get the logged in user in case someone comes to the site and is still logged in.   On the page I want to call this method.  Since I am passing the user service to all my controllers I don't know which controller will be in use since I won't know what page they're landing on.

I have the following User Service

```
app.factory('userService', function ($window) {
    var root = {};
    root.get_current_user = function(http){
        var config = {
        params: {}
    };
    http.post("/api/user/show", null, config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data.success == true) {
                user = data.user;

                show_authenticated();
            }

        });
    };
    return root;
});
```

Here is an empty controller I'm trying to inject the service into

```
app.controller('myResourcesController', function($scope, $http, userService) {

});
```

So on the top of my index file I want to have something along the lines of

```
controller.get_current_user();
```

This will be called from all the pages though so I'm not sure the syntax here.  All examples I found related to calling a specific controller, and usually from within another controller.  Perhaps this needs to go into my angularjs somewhere and not simply within a script tag on my index page.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't call that service when Angular initializes?  I don't see the reason why you'd need it to be called from *everywhere* if you only need it for when the page gets refreshed, which is the only time where Angular would initialize.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that, that's probably the best place to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run factory initialization in `run` method of your angular application.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies
E.g.

```
app.run(['userService', function(userService) {
  userService.get_current_user();
}]);
```

And `userService` factory should store authenticated user object internaly.

```
...
if (data.success == true) {
  root.user = data.user;
}
...
```

Then you will be able to use your factory in any controller

```
app.controller('myController', ['userService', function(userService) {
   //alert(userService.user);
}]);
```

Comment: I'm only storing it externally so other items on the page can interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject $http through the factory constructor function, for firsts

```
app.factory('userService', function ($window, $http) {
    var root = {};
    root.get_current_user = function(){
        var config = {
        params: {}
    };
    $http.post("/api/user/show", null, config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data.success == true) {
                user = data.user;

                show_authenticated();
            }

        });
    };
    return root;
});
```

in your controller you can say

```
$scope.get_current_user = UserService.get_current_user();
```

ng attributes in your html if needed.  besides this, i am not sure what you need.